# tensorflow.js - image prediction - main color of image

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorflow.js

I hope you can help me. I'm fooling around with my first tensorflow.js Model a little and got stuck by improving it.

The Task it should predict sounds "simple" : get color of object in Image.

But I'm stuck maybe someone can give me a hint :-)

My model:

- sequential
- conv2d:  filters: 32,
         kernelSize: [3, 3],
         padding: "same",
         inputShape: [32, 32, 3],
         kernelInitializer: "varianceScaling",
- activation: relu
- maxPooling2D: PoolSize: [2,2] strides: 2
- dropOut: rate 0.5
- conv2d:  filters: 64,
         kernelSize: [3, 3],
         padding: "same",
         kernelInitializer: "varianceScaling",
- activation: relu
- maxPooling2D: PoolSize: [2,2] strides: 2
- dropOut: rate 0.5
- flatten
- dense: units: 1024
- activation: relu
- batchNormalization: axis -1
- dropout: 0.5
- dense: units  (e.g.22)
- activation: softmax

[summary of my Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5MNn.png)

---

**My Data**

- one List of all colors which exist inside data (total 22 entries)
- an array of image dir to their mapped color example [ [dir=>"img/image1.jpeg", label: "red"],[dir=>"img/image2.jpeg", label: "black"]

---

**My Process**

*For Images*
Read Image with tf.node.decodeJpeg

Normalize it and push it into array of tensors

```
const offset = tf.scalar(127.5);
var tensor=tf.node.decodeJpeg(img, 3).resizeNearestNeighbor([32,32])
tensor = tensor.toFloat();
tensor = tensor.sub(offset).div(offset);
imageTensorArray.push(tensor);
```

*for Label*

get Numeric Index of Labels from Alllabels Array and oneHot binarize it.

```
var imageLabels = imageLabelArray.map(function (d) {
        return allLabelsUnique.indexOf(d[1]); //index of label String in allLabels
    });
const imageLabelsHot=tf.oneHot(imageLabels, allLabelsUnique.length);
```

*compile Model*

```
const optimizer = tf.train.adam(1e-3, 1e-3 / 20);
model.compile({
    optimizer: optimizer,
    loss: "categoricalCrossentropy",
    metrics: ['accuracy']
});
```

*train Model*

```
 await model.fit(trainImageTensors //5000, trainImageLabels //5000, {  ///all in the right order 
        epochs: 20,
        verbose: 1,
        validationSplit: 0.3,
        shuffle: 1,
        batchSize: 32
    });
```

---

Now my Problem(s):

- acc is getting better - val_acc stucks at ~ 0.339, loss: decrease - val_loss not regardless of epochs or amount of training data
- prediction is always black

I've played around a lot but i can't get the "one" hint for help

- trainImageTensors = tf.stack(buildImageToTensor(image)) - could this be a problem?

Model Pipeline:

I have a csv it is just 
color_i, color_ii, url to Picture

I Then check if it is already on my local disc if not i download it an save it in a smaller size:

```
img=canvas.loadImage(imageUrl) 
var cvs = new canvas.Canvas(32, 32);
var ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height);
var data = ctx.canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg').split(',');
            var buf = new Buffer.alloc(data[1].length, data[1], 'base64');
var dir = getlocalDir(url);
if (!fs.existsSync('img')) {
 fs.mkdirSync('img');
}
fs.writeFileSync(dir.toString(), buf, '');
```

After I have the picture i or if it already on the storage I read it as a Tensor using builtin functions

```
 //if local exists
 var dir = getlocalDir(url)
 var img = fs.readFileSync(dir);
 var tensor = tf.node.decodeJpeg(img, 3);
 //if not exists - ctx still there at the moment
 var tensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(ctx.canvas);
// then doing normalization
 tensor = tensor.toFloat();
 tensor = tensor.div(255.0);
 tensor = tf.image.cropAndResize(tensor.expandDims(0), [[15, 15, 30, 30]], [0], [15, 15], 'nearest').reshape([15, 15, 3]);
 imageTensorArray.push(tensor);
```

After this the work beginns

```
const trainImageTensors = tf.slice(imageTensorArray, 0, totalSum);

///dataArray.images: [0]=>Url, [1]=>color (red,blue,green, etc...)
///dataArray.labels: collection of all colors available in dataset
var imageLabels = dataArray.images.map(function (d) {      
        return dataArray.labels.indexOf(d[1]);
    });

const imageLabelsHot = tf.oneHot(imageLabels, dataArray.labels.length);
const trainImageLabels = tf.slice(imageLabelsHot, 0, totalSum);
 const optimizer = tf.train.adam(0.00001, 0.00001 / 50,);
    model.compile({
        optimizer: optimizer,
        loss: "categoricalCrossentropy",
        metrics: ['accuracy']
    });

    await model.fit(trainImageTensors, trainImageLabels, {
        epochs: 50,
        verbose: 1,
        validationSplit: 0.4,
        shuffle: 1,
        batchSize: 100,
    });
```

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with the image process. To be sure, how are you fitting your model with the data `imageTensorArray` ?

Comment: Hi There. Thank you for your reply. I got Ill last week so sorry for the late response.

`const trainImageTensors = tf.slice(imageTensorArray, 0, totalSum);`

and later

`await model.fit(trainImageTensors, trainImageLabels , {  
        epochs: 20,
        verbose: 1,
        validationSplit: 0.3,
        shuffle: 1,
        batchSize: 32
    });`

I've found out that the classweight hase some increasing but had no time yet to verify it more :)

Comment: You are pushing `tensors` to the array `imageTensorArray` are you concataning them after ? I would like to see `imageTensorArray` from its assignement to its use.
Can you add your whole model pipeline to the question if possible?

Comment: Thanks for your replay, and again sorry for late response hat do move on with other projects but now time for researching further :).

I added the Pipeline of the data and the Modeling hope it will help. I Found out, that if i make changes in the Classweights i can increase a little the values but no big deal :/

Comment: Sorry for my last response. Did you try to print the predicted and some of the training tensors and see if they really contain the image of interest ?